# Farm Based SharePoint Workflow requires Workflow Manager

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, workflow-manager

We are working on SharePoint 2013 on-premises. I am new bee on SharePoint 2013 workflows. We have the following requirement for creating old 2010 type farm based workflows using Visual Studio.

We were trying to understand, if it is required to install and configure Workflow Manager for this situation? Or we can still live without Workflow Manager? As per my research Workflow Manager would be used only in case of those declarative workflows created from Visual Studio and deployed as Sandbox solution to the SharePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflow Manager is only required for the new '2013' style workflow (.NET 4.0) functionality. SharePoint 2013 still has the 2010 workflow engine baked in.

If you only require the older 2010 style workflow functionality there is no requirement to add Workflow Manager to the farm.

Note that Workflow Manager is required if you wish to use 2013 style functionality at all, for example if you want to be able to create new 2013 functionality workflows using SharePoint Designer, then you would need Workflow Manager.

Comment: Thanks, It solved by creating a sample farm based solution and deploy. Whereas I was not able to deploy the 2013 style workflows without installing and configuring Workflow Manager